# How do you unsubscribe from a live stream

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to understand how to unsubscribe from an Observable that is created from a live feed.
Here is more or less the code:

```
SomeFeed feed = new SomeFeed();
Observable<PriceTick> observable = Observable.create(s ->
  feed.register(new SomeListener() {
    @Override
    public void priceTick(PriceTick event) {
      s.onNext(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(Throwable throwable) {
      s.onError(throwable);
    }
  })
);
Subscription subscription = observable.subscribe(System.out::println);
subscription.unsubscribe();
System.out.println("Is unsubscribed:" + subscription.isUnsubscribed()); // prints true
```

I am finding that after the subscription is unsubscribed, the subscriber is still outputting the event stream.

How can I get the unsubscribe to remove the subscriber from receiving further notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable you are creating doesn't obey the Observable contract. You are not handling unsubscribtion and backpreasure. `Observable.create` makes it easy to create such observables.

Instead you can use other techniques to create your observables. You can create observables with the `defer` operator or with `Observable.fromCallable`.

For your code you can use:

```
Observable<PriceTick> observable = Observable.create(s ->
  feed.register(new SomeListener() {
    @Override
    public void priceTick(PriceTick event) {
      if(!s.isUnsbscribed()) {
        s.onNext(event);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void error(Throwable throwable) {
      if(!s.isUnsbscribed()) {
        s.onError(throwable);
      }
    }
  })
);
```

This still doesn't handle backpreasure.

More about creating observables [here](https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/).